# why terraform try to update an attribute called 'terraform_labels' to an existing GCP resource when terraform plan

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

when I perform 'terraform plan', terraform try to update an  attribute called 'terraform_labels'
to an existing GCP resource already having an attribute called 'labels'.
like this

---

module.create_xx.google_compute_disk.xx_disk will be updated in-place  
 ~ resource "google_compute_disk" "xx_disk " {
 ~ name                        = "disk-xx-example"  
 ~ terraform_labels            = {
 + "owner" = "com"  }
 (12 unchanged attributes hidden)

---

I just applied it but, In the case of the google_compute_instance_template resource, 'in-place update' is not supported, resulting in the error 'doesnt support' update'

I tried adding an attribute called "terraform_label" to the code, but an error called "Value for unconfigurable attribute" occurred.

The attribute 'terraform_label' doesn't appear to be customizable, and I'm wondering why this update attempt keeps happening and how to fix it

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk#terraform_labels

Comment: I've already read it, but that code is just one example and what I was wondering is why terraform wants to update the argument 'terraform_label'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `google_compute_disk`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk), `terraform_labels` is:

> - `terraform_labels` - The combination of labels configured directly on the resource and default labels configured on the provider.

There are therefore two different ways that this attribute could change:

- You change [the `labels` argument](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/compute_disk#labels) directly in your `resource "google_compute_disk"` block.
- You change [the `default_labels` argument in your `provider "google"` block](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/guides/provider_reference#default_labels), which can contribute additional labels to the `terraform_labels` attribute on *all* resources belonging to that provider configuration.

---

If the provider is proposing to update the `terraform_labels` attribute on a `google_compute_instance_template` resource instance but then failing to do so once the plan is applied, that seems like a bug in the provider: the provider should not propose to take an action that it cannot actually take.

It seems like someone has already encountered and reported this bug as [Issue #16374 in the provider's GitHub repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-google/issues/16374). I would suggest subscribing to that issue in case the provider development team shares information about workarounds or releases a new version of the provider with the problem corrected.

Comment: I think there's someone who has similar concerns as me. Thank you. I'll subscribe